# How to bind arrays from resource and normal array into one array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-resources

I thought this to bind two arrays from resource into one array:

```
Resource res=getResources();

final int[] one_array=res.getIntArray(R.array.first_array) + res.getIntArray(R.array.second_array);
```

But variable array can't be declared like that showing:

```
The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int[]
```

Also I would like to bind two arrays from resource + one array into one array. In my thought, it should be:

```
Resource res=getResource();

final int[] one_array={ 1,2,3,4,5,res.getIntArray(R.array.first_array),res.getIntArray(R.array.second_array) };
```

But variable array can't be declared like that showing:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from 
     int[] to int
```

How can I achieve declaring one array by binding two arrays from resources and normal array?
Is there another/alternative ways/solutions to bind arrays?

Answer (score 4):

Try [ArrayUtils.addAll](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5b%5d,%20T...%29)

```
final int[] one_array = ArrayUtils.addAll(res.getIntArray(R.array.first_array), res.getIntArray(R.array.second_array);
```

`+` operator will concat two string.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you don't want to include the whole jar for just this operation, define your own helper method based on the `addAll()` source code. In the end, all it really does is `System.arrayCopy()` both arrays into one larger array.

```
/**
 * <p>Adds all the elements of the given arrays into a new array.</p>
 * <p>The new array contains all of the element of <code>array1</code> followed
 * by all of the elements <code>array2</code>. When an array is returned, it is always
 * a new array.</p>
 *
 * <pre>
 * ArrayUtils.addAll(array1, null)   = cloned copy of array1
 * ArrayUtils.addAll(null, array2)   = cloned copy of array2
 * ArrayUtils.addAll([], [])         = []
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param array1  the first array whose elements are added to the new array.
 * @param array2  the second array whose elements are added to the new array.
 * @return The new int[] array.
 * @since 2.1
 */
public static int[] addAll(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    if (array1 == null) {
        return clone(array2);
    } else if (array2 == null) {
        return clone(array1);
    }
    int[] joinedArray = new int[array1.length + array2.length];
    System.arraycopy(array1, 0, joinedArray, 0, array1.length);
    System.arraycopy(array2, 0, joinedArray, array1.length, array2.length);
    return joinedArray;
}
```

[Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.java#ArrayUtils.addAll%28int%5B%5D%2Cint%5B%5D%29) (Apache 2.0 license).

Comment: what if three parameters are required? I want to add three arrays. @MH

Comment: @InnkuanThute: Just follow the same pattern as outlined above. In short, the most important part will be adding another `System.arrayCopy()` call for the third array. Even better: make the method work on any number of arrays. I'll leave that as a homework excersize up to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe default jdk don't use ArrayUtils class
if you want use default jdk to bind array 
use below code.

```
    int a[] = new int[11];
    int b[] = new int[21];
    int c[] = new int[a.length + b.length];

    System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, a.length, b.length);
```